# memory allocation of N bytes failed in python polars with parquet files

Tags: python-polars

I tried to read 200 parquet files having a total size of 21 GB in a machine having enough specifications and RAM to handle this data read. I am getting the error: memory allocation of 153222400 bytes failed

**System Usage and Specifications**
[image: System Usage and Specifications]

Could anyone please help how to troubleshoot and solve this?

I tried the below code to perform the read operation.

data=pl.scan_parquet(r'item_data_storage*.parquet')

data = data.collect()

I also tried using data.collect(streaming=True) but the same error.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, 21GB in Parquet format correspond to more than 21GB in RAM as Parquet is a compressed format. So it makes sense that your data does not fit into memory.

But that is ok, because you can use the streaming functionality of Polars. With the streaming functionality of Polars, you can process data bigger than RAM by splitting it into multiple chunks and processing the chunks sequentially.

For that, you can use `scan_parquet` (as you are using already), and then `sink_parquet` to save the file to disk.

`collect` and `collect(streaming=True)` materialize the result of your query into the RAM, so it will not work unless you are doing some filtering and aggregations so that the result can fit in RAM.

So you can replace `collect` with `sink_parquet`.

Final note: the streaming functionality for Polars is in active development so not all operations are supported yet.

Comment: I tried to run the below transformation and then used sink_parquet but I am getting below error.

input query:
vocab_df = vocab_df.groupby('col_1')\ 
.agg(pl.concat_list (pl.col ('col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7', 'col_8'))
.alias('ref_info'))\ 
.select(pl.col('col_1','ref_info')) 

output expected (2 columns):
col_1 (i64) | ref_info (list[list[str]])

pyo3_runtime.PanicException: sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'

Comment: Hi @RakeshChaudhary, can you share how you create the vocab_df?

Indeed some operations are not supported by sink_parquet at the moment

Comment: vocab_df = pl.scan_parquet('*. parquet)

Comment: @RakeshChaudhary got it. There must be some calculation which does not support streaming yet. You can check out this blog to find out which operations can run in streaming mode https://www.rhosignal.com/posts/streaming-chunk-sizes/#is-my-query-running-in-streaming-mode

Answer (score 0):

Your machine has 64GB RAM, and the parquet files on disk are 21GB, so you may expect this to work. However, data in Parquet is compressed, meaning that in-memory sizes will be larger. See also [Why reading a parquet dataset requires much more memory than the size of the dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74236493/why-reading-a-parquet-dataset-requires-much-more-memory-than-the-size-of-the-dat)

In terms of solutions. The `scan_parquet` solution will only work if you actually reduce the dataset in size, for example by selecting a subset of columns or filter out rows. If you do `scan_parquet` + `collect`, you may as well use `read_parquet` directly. This user guide page should help you better understand what lazy is: [link](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/concepts/lazy-vs-eager/). So there is no solution for loading data that is larger than memory all in memory. You will need to write your filtering/calculation logic before calling `collect`.